# Semisimplicity of Frobenius operation on etale cohomology?

Tags: etale-cohomology

Let $X_0$ be a variety defined over a finite field of characteristic $p \neq l$. 
Is it true, that the action of the frobenius on the l-adic cohomology $H_l^*(X)$ is semisimple (say for smooth $X_0$)? If not, what would be a counter-example?

Comment: See Emerton's comment to Bondarko's question "Morphisms between pure complexes of sheaves". He says that semi-simplicity of Frobenius is part of the Tate conjectures.

Comment: This is famous open problem... It is true for abelian varieties.

Comment: Also true for K3 surfaces, by Deligne. See Lei Fu's AMS article 'On the semisimplicity conjecture and Galois representations' for more info. For mixed cohomology groups, the weight filtration does not split in general (it would be split if Frobenius were always semisimple), and examples can be found already in dimension 1.

Comment: @Jan Weidner. The connection with the standard conjectures is explained in Kleiman's article "The standard conjectures" in the first volume of the proceedings of the conference on Motives (ed. Jannsen, Kleiman, Serre), th. 5-6, p. 19.

Comment: @Damian: Here is the precise reference:  Kleiman, Steven L., The standard conjectures.  Motives (Seattle,WA, 1991), 3–20, Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 55, Part 1, Amer. Math. Soc.,Providence, RI, 1994.

Comment: @Geordie: Your reference is to the MO question 

mathoverflow.net/questions/22699/

Comment: @shenghao: Fu's article is freely available online.

http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2001-353-11/S0002-9947-01-02814-8/home.html?




Comment: @Jan: My limited experience with Frobenius operation comes from Deligne-Lusztig character theory for finite reductive groups.  Here you need affine varieties and cohomology with compact support.  The semisimplicity conjecture only seems to arise for projective varieties.  Anyway, I'm unclear about what the truth of the conjecture would imply?   In  Deligne-Lusztig theory, the Frobenius operation plays an essential auxiliary role but at most its eigenvalues on etale cohomology seem needed.  (In their book Digne-Michel just write: "note that *F* is not necessarily semi-simple".)

Answer (score 21):

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a finite field 
$\mathbb{F}_{q}$ of caracteristic $p$ and let $l$ be a prime number different from p.
 We consider the following statement :

(A) The action of the Frobenius on the etale cohomology $H^{i}_{et}( X_{\overline{\mathbb{F}}_{q}}, \mathbb{Q}_{l})$ is semisimple.

How to suppress the projective hypothesis is the subject of the mathoverflow question 
[link text](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104627/example-of-non-projective-variety-with-non-semisimple-frobenius-action-on-etale-c)

(A) is true in the following cases :

1) $X=A$ an abelian variety (and so for $X$ a curve via the jacobian).
As mentionned in comment by Emerton, it is a consequence of the Weil's
work on the Riemann hypothesis in this case.
Fix a polarization on $A$. For $x$ an endomorphism of $X$ which gives an endomorphim on $H^{1}_{et}$, we can define an endomorphism $x'$ (' : "Rosati involution") by $x' = *x^{T}* $
where in the middle we have the transposition with respect to the intersection product
and * comes from the duality theory of abelian varieties ( the polarisation gives a identification between $H^{1}_{et}(A)$ and $H^{1}_{et}(\check{A})$).
Weil proved that $Tr(xx')>0$ if $x$ is non-zero. Let $F$ be the (geometric) Frobenius. For
$x = q^{-1/2}F$, we have x'=$x^{-1}$. So $Tr(aa')$ is a definite positive bilinear form 
on the $\mathbb{Q}$ algebra generated by x and is preserved by multiplication by $x$ : so
multiplication by $x$ is unitary which shows that $x$ is semi-simple (and eigenvalues 
of modulus one gives the Riemann hypothesis).

2) $X$ a K3 surface. As mentionned in comment by shenghao, it is a consequence of the work of Deligne : [link text](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/16_ConjectureDeWeilK3.pdf)
The result is deduced from the case of abelian varieties 
via the Kuga-Satake construction (of course there is a non-trivial thing to do because
Kuga-Satake construction is a priori of transcendental nature but Deligne did it).

For $X$ general, (A) is conjectured. It is a consequence of standard conjectures. More precisely, things should work as in the case of abelian varieties. We can still define 
$x \mapsto x'$ at the cohomological level but $Tr(xx')>0$ is conjectural : a standard conjecture 
of Lefschetz type implies $x'$ algebraic if $x$ is, which permits to use a trace formula 
expressing $Tr(xx')$ as an intersection product. The positivity should then be a consequence of a standard conjecture of Hodge type.
For more details, as mentionned in comment by Damian Rössler, see Kleiman "The standard conjectures" (whose some details depend on Kleiman, "Algebraic cycles and the Weil conjectures").

Comment: Thanks, do you know a source where it is discussed how my question relates to the standard conjectures? 

Also is it known whether semisimplicity of cohomology fails without the assumptions smooth / projective?

Comment: I'm not sure if Faltings' work leads to semisimplicity of the $Gal(\bar{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q)$-representation, which is a different conjecture. 

Comment: @shenghao. It does (for abelian varieties); see the original article or the translation in Cornell-Silverman.

Comment: Dear unknown, The semisimplicity of Frobenius on the $\ell$-adic cohomology of a curve over a finite field is not due to Faltings; it goes back to the foundational theory of abelian varieties (due to Weil in the non-complex setting, perhaps?).  Faltings's results pertain to the context of curves and abelian varieties over number fields.  Regards,

Comment: Dear unknown, This is a nice survey of the situation.  Regards,

Comment: I have edited my answer because as mentionned by various comments, my remark on the link with Faltings's work was not correct.

Comment: The reason why 1) is true is much more elementary: $F$ is central in the semi-simple algebra $End^0(A)$, hence it is semi-simple. So it acts semi-simply on $H^1_{et}(A)$ and its exterior powers $H^i_{et}(A)$.